# Can we run multiple similar commands using a single command with *

Tags: unix, terminal, command

I have to run following list of commands in terminal

```
run A1
run A2
run A3
 .....
run A100
```

can we use something similar like run A*, instead of adding all those lines to a file and sourcing the file.

where `A1`,...,`A100` are files.

Comment: Have you tried it to see? You could always use a for loop.

Comment: are `A1`,...,`A100` files?

Comment: Try something like: `for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo "run A"$i |sh; done` or 
 `for i in $(seq 1 100); do "run A"$i; done` (even easier)

Comment: Yes @Allan A1 to A100 are files

Comment: `bash <(printf 'run %s\n' A{1..100})`, or, if `run` can take multiple arguments, just `run A{1..100}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `A1`,...,`A100` are files you can directly use the following command:

```
find $DIR -type f -name 'A*' -print | xargs -n1 run
```

the find command will look for all files that start with a `A` and then using xargs you give the result one after another to your `run` command

Answer (score 2):

Try Any Looping technique.

Eg:-
Write the below in a script and run that script when you need to execute all the commands at one shot.

```
 for i in {1..100}
    do
     # your-unix-command-here ( run A$i)
    done
```